# Inequality with complex numbers involving modules

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \Bbb C$ so as $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$ and let $a=|z_1-z_2|, b=|z_2-z_3|, c=|z_3-z_1|$. Show, using algebraic methods, that:
$$ \frac {1} {(a+b-c)^2}+ \frac {1} {(b+c-a)^2}+ \frac {1} {(a+c-b)^2} \ge 1.$$

Comment: Try writing $z_1$ as $\cos(x)+ i \ \sin(x)$ and so on and see what you get.

Comment: Why don't you try drawing the points in the complex plain in order to understand geometrically what does the inequality mean? I'm sure that will make you know what kind of algebraic methods you'll need.

Comment: @ArcadioBuendía I tried to do this, but I didn't find any algebraic method. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit geometric. I'll use the fact that $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. It's clear that $$a+b+c\le 3\sqrt3.$$ Now call $a+b-c=x$, $a+c-b=y$, $b+c-a=z$. We have that $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=a+b+c$. By Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-HM
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\ge\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}{3}\ge\frac{3^3}{(x+y+z)^2}\ge\frac{3^3}{(3\sqrt3)^2}=1$$
and this is the desired inequality.